# How to assign the values to variable in angular 7

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

I am trying to assign the values to variable but not working.If anyone know please help to find the solution.

My code:

app.component.ts:

```
public power:any;
public ice:any;
public cake:any;

changeValue(prop,val){

this.[prop]=val;
console.log(this.[prop]);

}

this.changeValue("power","124525");
this.changeValue("ice","125658");
this.changeValue("cake","122568");
```

Comment: Write `this[prop]`, not `this.[prop]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public power:any;
public ice:any;
public cake:any;

changeValue(prop,val){

this[prop]=val;
console.log(this[prop]);

}

this.changeValue("power","124525");
this.changeValue("ice","125658");
this.changeValue("cake","122568");
```